# Rollup summary on quote line editor

Tags: cpq, quote, quotelineitem

Is there a way to create a rollup summary field at the quote line editor level?
At the quote level object does not work for what I want to build l.

Comment: This question needs more information. What data are you looking to "roll up" (which field, from which object, and is it related to the QLI object)? Did you really mean to say that QLI _editor_ (i.e. the page that allows you to add multiple line items to a quote), or did you just mean the QLI object itself?